# Comparing detected face with array of existing faces with opencv in android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface, face-recognition

I'm making face recognition app via opencv. I can detect faces and I have few faces in resources.
I'm stack on this place:

```
// These vectors hold the images and corresponding labels.
vector<Mat> images;
vector<int> labels;

Mat testSample = images[images.size() - 1];
    int testLabel = labels[labels.size() - 1];
    images.pop_back();
    labels.pop_back();


    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
    model->train(images, labels);

    string result_message = format("Predicted class = %d / Actual class = %d.", predictedLabel, testLabel);
    cout << result_message << endl;
    // Here is how to get the eigenvalues of this Eigenfaces model:
    Mat eigenvalues = model->getMat("eigenvalues");
    // And we can do the same to display the Eigenvectors (read Eigenfaces):
    Mat W = model->getMat("eigenvectors");
    // Get the sample mean from the training data
    Mat mean = model->getMat("mean");
```

Can please, somebody explain me, where exactly I should put my detected faces and where I compare them with database? I have to put all of them inside this `vector<Mat> images;` or what?
How also works field `vector<int> labels;`? what I should write in there?
Would be great if somebody can write to me simple example. Detected faces I'm passing as parameter from Java class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the class FaceRecognizer that comes with javacv library (com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer) :

The following is the class code, it contains all functions that you need to train and test faces

```
package org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition;

import static  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.*;
import static  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.*;
import static  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.*;
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.FaceRecognizer;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.MatVector;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public  class PersonRecognizer {

public final static int MAXIMG = 100;
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer;
String mPath;
int count=0;
labels labelsFile;

 static  final int WIDTH= 128;
 static  final int HEIGHT= 128;;
 private int mProb=999;


PersonRecognizer(String path)
{
  faceRecognizer =  com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(2,8,8,8,200);
 // path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/facerecog/faces/";
 mPath=path;
 labelsFile= new labels(mPath);


}

void changeRecognizer(int nRec)
{
    switch(nRec) {
    case 0: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer(1,8,8,8,100);
            break;
    case 1: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createFisherFaceRecognizer();
            break;
    case 2: faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
            break;
    }
    train();

}

void add(Mat m, String description) {
    Bitmap bmp= Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(), m.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(m,bmp);
    bmp= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, WIDTH, HEIGHT, false);

    FileOutputStream f;
    try {
        f = new FileOutputStream(mPath+description+"-"+count+".jpg",true);
        count++;
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, f);
        f.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error",e.getCause()+" "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}

public boolean train() {

    File root = new File(mPath);
    Log.i("mPath",mPath);
    FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");

    };
    };

    File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

    MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);

    int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

    int counter = 0;
    int label;

    IplImage img=null;
    IplImage grayImg;

    int i1=mPath.length();


    for (File image : imageFiles) {
        String p = image.getAbsolutePath();
        img = cvLoadImage(p);

        if (img==null)
            Log.e("Error","Error cVLoadImage");
        Log.i("image",p);

        int i2=p.lastIndexOf("-");
        int i3=p.lastIndexOf(".");
        int icount=Integer.parseInt(p.substring(i2+1,i3)); 
        if (count<icount) count++;

        String description=p.substring(i1,i2);

        if (labelsFile.get(description)<0)
            labelsFile.add(description, labelsFile.max()+1);

        label = labelsFile.get(description);

        grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

        cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);

        images.put(counter, grayImg);

        labels[counter] = label;

        counter++;
    }
    if (counter>0)
        if (labelsFile.max()>1)
            faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);
    labelsFile.Save();
return true;
}

public boolean canPredict()
{
    if (labelsFile.max()>1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

public String predict(Mat m) {
    if (!canPredict())
        return "";
    int n[] = new int[1];
    double p[] = new double[1];
    IplImage ipl = MatToIplImage(m,WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    faceRecognizer.predict(ipl, n, p);

    if (n[0]!=-1)
     mProb=(int)p[0];
    else
        mProb=-1;
    if (n[0] != -1)
        return labelsFile.get(n[0]);
    else
        return "Unkown";
}

  IplImage MatToIplImage(Mat m,int width,int heigth)
  {


       Bitmap bmp=Bitmap.createBitmap(m.width(), m.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


       Utils.matToBitmap(m, bmp);
       return BitmapToIplImage(bmp,width, heigth);

  }

IplImage BitmapToIplImage(Bitmap bmp, int width, int height) {

    if ((width != -1) || (height != -1)) {
        Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);
        bmp = bmp2;
    }

    IplImage image = IplImage.create(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(),
            IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);

    bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());

    IplImage grayImg = IplImage.create(image.width(), image.height(),
            IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);

    cvCvtColor(image, grayImg, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGR2GRAY);

    return grayImg;
}



protected void SaveBmp(Bitmap bmp,String path)
  {
        FileOutputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(path , true);

        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,file);  
        file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("",e.getMessage()+e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

  }


public void load() {
    train();

}

 public int getProb() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mProb;
 }

}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer, but I'm using JNI and I'd avoid using JavaCV... especially because I've tried, and nothing worked out...

Comment: have not you seen this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/tutorial/facerec_video_recognition.html ? there is a detailed code

Comment: yes, I'm following this tutorial, but I cannot understand where in this tutorial I apply BOTH pictures (detected faces and faces from database). There is shown only one Mat array called "images", but should I put there these "Both" or what? According to this would be a good example with using labels... those are just Ids (like int i from faces.size) or some specific names... I cannot find fully commented exactly this part...

Comment: There is not exactly as you want. Database of images will be trained using   model->train(images, labels), by now you have a model trained with a set of faces. Any other test face (detected face) will be matched with database by calling :
int prediction = model->predict(face_resized);
Here prediction is the degree of similarity (need more read about the value of prediction)

Comment: I think I understood what you mean. And as I clarified, field "label" I can fill simply 0, 1, 2, 3 etc for each person and int predictedLabel will contain this "id" of the image which matched... am I right? but what if image didn't match? there must be some scale of confidence... have you had a negative result of prediction? what is it saying?

Comment: yes you got it. confidence is the distance from your test image to the closest image in DB. to do reject the non found faces you need to do some work, try to run tests on your data with you choice of threshold to optimize the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
package org.tensorflow.lite.examples.test;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.CvException;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.face.EigenFaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.face.FaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.face.FisherFaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;


import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public  class PersonRecognizer {

  //  FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(1, 6, 6, 6, 13.5);
//2,2,12,12,15)
  //  FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer =  FisherFaceRecognizer.create(100,100.0);
 // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer =  FisherFaceRecognizer.create(0, 123.0);

 //   FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create(10, 123.0);

   // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = EigenFaceRecognizer.create(1,190.5);
  // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(1,8,8,8,123.0)
   FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(2, 8, 8, 8, 64);

  //  FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = LBPHFaceRecognizer.create(2,2,12,12,15);
    String mPath;
    int count=0;
    Labels labelsFile;

    static  final int WIDTH= 224;
    static  final int HEIGHT= 224;;
    private int mProb=999;


    PersonRecognizer(String path) {
        // path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/facerecog/faces/";
        mPath=path;
        labelsFile= new Labels(mPath);


    }


    void add(Bitmap m, String description) {

        Mat mat = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(m, mat);
        Mat mGray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat,mGray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        Bitmap bmp = null;
        FileOutputStream f;
        Mat tmp = new Mat (HEIGHT, WIDTH, CvType.CV_8U, new Scalar(4));
        try {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mGray, tmp, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
            bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tmp.cols(), tmp.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Utils.matToBitmap(tmp, bmp);
            f = new FileOutputStream(mPath+description+"-"+count+".jpg",true);
            count++;
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, f);
            f.close();
        }
        catch (CvException e) {
            Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error908",e.getCause()+" "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public boolean train() {

        File root = new File(mPath);

        FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {

                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            };
        };

        File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);

        List<Mat> images = new ArrayList<>();

        int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];

        int counter = 0;
        int label;

        int i1=mPath.length();
        for (File image : imageFiles) {
            Log.d("TAG11", "train: collecting");
            String p = image.getAbsolutePath();

            Mat imagexnm = org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(p, 0);

            int i2=p.lastIndexOf("-");
            int i3=p.lastIndexOf(".");
            int icount=Integer.parseInt(p.substring(i2+1,i3));
            if (count<icount) count++;

            String description=p.substring(i1,i2);

            if (labelsFile.get(description)<0)
                Log.d("TAG11", "train: add label");
                labelsFile.add(description, labelsFile.max()+1);

            label = labelsFile.get(description);



            images.add(imagexnm);

            labels[counter] = label;



            counter++;
        }
        if (counter>0)
            if (labelsFile.max()>1)
            {
                Mat labelsmat = new Mat(labels.length, 1, CvType.CV_32SC1);
                for(int i=0;i<labels.length;i++)
                {
                    labelsmat.put(i,0,labels[i]);
                }

                faceRecognizer.train(images, labelsmat);
                labelsFile.Save();
            }


        return true;
    }

    public boolean canPredict()
    {
        if (labelsFile.max()>1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public String predict(Bitmap m) {
        if (!canPredict())
            return "-1";
        int n[] = new int[1];
        double p[] = new double[1];



        Mat mat = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(m, mat);
        Mat mGray = new Mat();
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mat,mGray,Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
        faceRecognizer.predict(mGray, n, p);

        if (n[0]!=-1)
            mProb=(int)p[0];
        else
            mProb=-1;
        //  if ((n[0] != -1)&&(p[0]<95))
        if (n[0] != -1)
            return labelsFile.get(n[0]);
        else
            return "Unknown";
    }







    protected void SaveBmp(Bitmap bmp,String path)
    {
        FileOutputStream file;
        try {
            file = new FileOutputStream(path , true);

            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,file);
            file.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("",e.getMessage()+e.getCause());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    public void load() {
        train();

    }

    public int getProb() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mProb;
    }


}
```